# parse craigslist to extract e-mail addresses, and write script to automatically send my resume to job postings

Tags: regex, email, parsing, reply, craigslist

Thats right, this post is about "parsing craigslist to extract e-mail addresses, and writing script to automatically send my resume to job postings".

Being a computer science student and in senior year, I have had my rod out for awhile and only shawdy recruiters are nibbling - giving me false hope for senior developer roles I won't get.

So why spend hours clicking through craigslist job postings when I can probably just have an automated system of applying to EVERY job posting on craigslist in my area. I have spent too many hours going through online job application processes. I am probably not alone.

RSS, python regex, SQL database, yahoo pipes. What are some ideas some of you out there might have in regards to this idea?

Comment: That is only 1/4 of the answer to this problem, and is not a duplicate.

Comment: Just spamming job offers is probably not the best way to land your first job. A candidate who can not even spend 10 to 15 minutes looking into the company he/she want to work at is not a person I would like to hire.

Comment: a company that can't spend 2 minutes looking at my resume is not one I would want to work for

Comment: Your first job? I can see that, however with that attitude I would understand if you have trouble landing your first job. Graduate engineers are not hired for their expertise, believe it or not, but you do not know as much as you think. So companies are looking for people they think would be motivated and eager to learn and shows an interest for the company. If the mail looks the least bit as spam it just shows your lazy. The only merit might be that you solved a problem using computers.

Answer (score 4):

For scraping Craigslist, use the pyquery Python package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery

For a regex for email addresses, see the first example on this page:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

I don't think you need a relational database for storing the email addresses. Just output to csv:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

For sending your resume to these email addresses, try this:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/mail-merge/

For second thoughts, see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morality